# Mockito @Mock multiple objects using single annotation

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Is there a way to mock group of objects using single @Mock Annotation.
[Just trying to reduce lines of Code as, it turns out extremely ugly as number of Mock objects increase]

Eg:
Instead of

```
@Mock
private Foo foo;
@Mock
private Bar bar;
```

Can we Have something like

```
@Mock
private Foo foo;
private Bar foo;
```

Comment: No, there isn't. But if your goal is to reduce the number of lines, you can use `@Mock private Foo foo;`

Comment: If there are too many of lines having `@Mock` annotation and the class you are testing is not meant to hold data then it indicates class having too many external dependencies & possibly low cohesion and you should take a look at the design.

Comment: It's not a feature that will ever be implemented, It's not really feasible and the benefits are minimal. Firstly the logic that processes the `@mock` annotation only knows which field is annotated. Java syntax doesn't use linefeed as the end of a line, it doesn't group fields, it doesn't care about extra whitespace etc. If this feature was to be added to the mockito library, some developer would need to write custom source code parsers to decide where multiple fields have been arbitrarily grouped. And then of course mockito would need to know how to find your source at runtime...